# How to access external hard drive using swift filemanager

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to access files that are on an external hard drive connected to Mac using Swift 5.0 FileManager. The application prompts user for a folder, reads all image files, and categorizes based on exif data.

I have a NSOpenPanel() that allows user to select the directory and it gets the files that are in that directory

```
@IBAction func browseFile(sender: AnyObject) {

        let dialog = NSOpenPanel();

        dialog.title                   = "Choose a .txt file";
        dialog.showsResizeIndicator    = true;
        dialog.showsHiddenFiles        = false;
        dialog.canChooseDirectories    = true;
        dialog.canCreateDirectories    = true;
        dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
        dialog.canChooseFiles = false;

        if (dialog.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
            let result = dialog.url // Pathname of the file

            if (result != nil) {
                originalPhotoDirectory = result!
                originalDirectoryLabel.stringValue = result!.path
                //basic gist of the app
                let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: result,includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey.creationDateKey.self]);
                //then loops through files in directory and gets exif

            }
        } else {
            // User clicked on "Cancel"
            return
        }

    }
```

The program works fine for files on the computer, but whenever I try to select a external hard drive that is connected it crashes.

Comment: *it crashes* where? The code looks very *objective-c-ish*. At least remove the trailing semicolons. And you can replace `[URLResourceKey.creationDateKey.self]` just with `[.creationDateKey]`.

Comment: Are you saying the code works fine if you select a folder on an internal drive?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes the code works fine if a select a folder on an internal drive but when selecting a folder on a external usb hard drive it just crashes.